# Issue with insert query in Sqlite ?( variable insert)

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, android-sqlite, sql-insert

How can I insert variable value in Sqlite, I am unable to find the issue with my code, If I use insert statement as follows it is working and values are inserted,

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Locationlog (Coordinates, Location, Category, Address) VALUES ("manju", "kishor", "ramesh", "ram")');
```

If I try to insert as follows the values are not inserted,

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Locationlog (Coordinates, Location, Category, Address) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',[Latlongs,Location,Category,Address]);
```

does not work for the query like,

```
 tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Locationlog (Coordinates, Location, Category, Address) VALUES ('+Latlongs+', '+Location+', '+Category+', '+Address+')');
```

I am using TEXT as datatype for all columns, the input value size is in between 1-100. What is the maximum size for TEXT data type? Any one can suggest how to insert variables in insert query ?

```
var Latlongs = $("#defendLatlongs").val();
   var Location = $("#defendLocation").val();
   var Category = $("#defendcategory").val();
   var Address = $("#defendAddress").val();

   var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "MYDB"});
   db.transaction(function (tx) {
   tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Locationlog (Coordinates TEXT, Location TEXT, Category TEXT, Address TEXT)');
     });
  db.transaction(function (tx){
  tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Locationlog (Coordinates, Location, Category, Address) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',[Latlongs,Location,Category,Address]);


 });

 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add id attribute

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "MYDB"});
db.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Locationlog (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Coordinates TEXT,    Location TEXT, Category TEXT, Address TEXT)');
 });
db.transaction(function (tx){
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Locationlog (Coordinates, Location, Category, Address) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',   [Latlongs,Location,Category,Address]);
```