# Basic Javascript SQL Insert Function Error

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite

I'm breaking my bigger problem into a few bitesize chunks to resolve.
I'm practicing Javascript/SQL interactions - and failing at the third hurdle, being inserting data:

```js
var databaseOptions = {
    fileName: "sqlite_WAtest",
    version: "1.0",
    displayName: "SQLite WA Test",
    maxSize: 1024
}; // End databaseOptions



var database = openDatabase(
    databaseOptions.fileName,
    databaseOptions.version,
    databaseOptions.displayName,
    databaseOptions.maxSize
); // End database



database.transaction(
    function( transaction ){

        // Create our table if it doesn't exist
        transaction.executeSql(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WORKOUTS (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, WOdate, WOtype);");

    },function(){
        alert('error Creating!');
    },function(){
        alert('success Creating');
    }
); // end database.transaction



// Try and insert dummy info into table
database.transaction(
    function( transaction ){

        // Insert the data
        transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO WORKOUTS (WOdate, WOtype) VALUES ("Test 1","Test 2")');

    },function(){
        alert('error inserting!');
    },function(){
        alert('success inserting');
    }
); // end database.transaction
```

When I load this page the alert fires saying "success creating!" - good news.

However I then get "error inserting" = not so good news.

The error is that there is no column named WOdate in the table WORKOUTS.

I've re-written the INSERT code a few times but I can't get it to work how I would expect it to. I'm tracking the table in the Safari Storage window and no data is getting into the table.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

EDIT: The issue was I already had a table in place without the correct columns. I have added this for the purpose of my experiment which made the code work:

```
   // Delete the table before running - because I'm testing
    // This is needed
    //
    database.transaction(
        function( transaction ){

            // Drop table
            transaction.executeSql(
                "DROP TABLE WORKOUTS");

        },function(err){
            alert('error Dropping: ' + err.code + '; Message: ' + err.message);
        },function(){
            alert('success Dropping');
        }
    ); // end database.transaction
```

Two lessons learned for me here:
  1) Error call back handling - make use of the .code and .message properties and flag these. Helps narrow down the problem.
  2) Be wary of existing data when testing/building

Comment: There must be a way to check the exact error message, `error inserting` says nothing about what's happened.

Comment: Don't you need to pass two or more params when doing an insert?  The example inserts I've seen look like `transaction.executeSql('insert into people (name, shirt) VALUES ("Joe", "Green");', [], nullDataHandler, errorHandler);`

Comment: I'd assume that the error handler function gets passed a parameter which has a description of the error somewhere.

Comment: Related question: [Issue with insert query in Sqlite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22804527/issue-with-insert-query-in-sqlite-variable-insert)

Comment: I've added a bit more detail on the error - The error is that there is no column named WOdate in the table WORKOUTS.

Comment: Could you tag your question with the database engine you use? Sqlite?

Comment: And is there a column WOdate in WORKOUTS? I see it is in the CREATE statement, but if the table already exists, then that CREATE is not executed.

Comment: Yes as ridiculous as this is, the issue was the table format. I had previously 'created' a table with different columns and that was the problem. I have solved this now by dropping the table first. Post amended.